# Different values for the same key from a hash function and good sort of hash values

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, hash

I have to execute MurmurHash3, a hash function. But I get strange results.
And I'm wondering if I'm using the function badly:

**MurmurHash3.cpp**

```
 #include "MurmurHash3.h"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Platform-specific functions and macros

// Microsoft Visual Studio

#if defined(_MSC_VER)

#define FORCE_INLINE    __forceinline

#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROTL32(x,y) _rotl(x,y)
#define ROTL64(x,y) _rotl64(x,y)

#define BIG_CONSTANT(x) (x)

// Other compilers

#else   // defined(_MSC_VER)

#define FORCE_INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))

inline uint32_t rotl32 ( uint32_t x, int8_t r )
{
  return (x << r) | (x >> (32 - r));
}

inline uint64_t rotl64 ( uint64_t x, int8_t r )
{
  return (x << r) | (x >> (64 - r));
}

#define ROTL32(x,y) rotl32(x,y)
#define ROTL64(x,y) rotl64(x,y)

#define BIG_CONSTANT(x) (x##LLU)

#endif // !defined(_MSC_VER)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Block read - if your platform needs to do endian-swapping or can only
// handle aligned reads, do the conversion here

FORCE_INLINE uint32_t getblock32 ( const uint32_t * p, int i )
{
  return p[i];
}

FORCE_INLINE uint64_t getblock64 ( const uint64_t * p, int i )
{
  return p[i];
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Finalization mix - force all bits of a hash block to avalanche

FORCE_INLINE uint32_t fmix32 ( uint32_t h )
{
  h ^= h >> 16;
  h *= 0x85ebca6b;
  h ^= h >> 13;
  h *= 0xc2b2ae35;
  h ^= h >> 16;

  return h;
}

//----------

FORCE_INLINE uint64_t fmix64 ( uint64_t k )
{
  k ^= k >> 33;
  k *= BIG_CONSTANT(0xff51afd7ed558ccd);
  k ^= k >> 33;
  k *= BIG_CONSTANT(0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53);
  k ^= k >> 33;

  return k;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------



void MurmurHash3_x86_128 ( const void * key, const int len,
                           uint32_t seed, void * out )
{
  const uint8_t * data = (const uint8_t*)key;
  const int nblocks = len / 16;

  uint32_t h1 = seed;
  uint32_t h2 = seed;
  uint32_t h3 = seed;
  uint32_t h4 = seed;

  const uint32_t c1 = 0x239b961b; 
  const uint32_t c2 = 0xab0e9789;
  const uint32_t c3 = 0x38b34ae5; 
  const uint32_t c4 = 0xa1e38b93;

  //----------
  // body

  const uint32_t * blocks = (const uint32_t *)(data + nblocks*16);

  for(int i = -nblocks; i; i++)
  {
    uint32_t k1 = getblock32(blocks,i*4+0);
    uint32_t k2 = getblock32(blocks,i*4+1);
    uint32_t k3 = getblock32(blocks,i*4+2);
    uint32_t k4 = getblock32(blocks,i*4+3);

    k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL32(k1,15); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;

    h1 = ROTL32(h1,19); h1 += h2; h1 = h1*5+0x561ccd1b;

    k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL32(k2,16); k2 *= c3; h2 ^= k2;

    h2 = ROTL32(h2,17); h2 += h3; h2 = h2*5+0x0bcaa747;

    k3 *= c3; k3  = ROTL32(k3,17); k3 *= c4; h3 ^= k3;

    h3 = ROTL32(h3,15); h3 += h4; h3 = h3*5+0x96cd1c35;

    k4 *= c4; k4  = ROTL32(k4,18); k4 *= c1; h4 ^= k4;

    h4 = ROTL32(h4,13); h4 += h1; h4 = h4*5+0x32ac3b17;
  }

  //----------
  // tail

  const uint8_t * tail = (const uint8_t*)(data + nblocks*16);

  uint32_t k1 = 0;
  uint32_t k2 = 0;
  uint32_t k3 = 0;
  uint32_t k4 = 0;

  switch(len & 15)
  {
  case 15: k4 ^= tail[14] << 16;
  case 14: k4 ^= tail[13] << 8;
  case 13: k4 ^= tail[12] << 0;
           k4 *= c4; k4  = ROTL32(k4,18); k4 *= c1; h4 ^= k4;

  case 12: k3 ^= tail[11] << 24;
  case 11: k3 ^= tail[10] << 16;
  case 10: k3 ^= tail[ 9] << 8;
  case  9: k3 ^= tail[ 8] << 0;
           k3 *= c3; k3  = ROTL32(k3,17); k3 *= c4; h3 ^= k3;

  case  8: k2 ^= tail[ 7] << 24;
  case  7: k2 ^= tail[ 6] << 16;
  case  6: k2 ^= tail[ 5] << 8;
  case  5: k2 ^= tail[ 4] << 0;
           k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL32(k2,16); k2 *= c3; h2 ^= k2;

  case  4: k1 ^= tail[ 3] << 24;
  case  3: k1 ^= tail[ 2] << 16;
  case  2: k1 ^= tail[ 1] << 8;
  case  1: k1 ^= tail[ 0] << 0;
           k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL32(k1,15); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;
  };

  //----------
  // finalization

  h1 ^= len; h2 ^= len; h3 ^= len; h4 ^= len;

  h1 += h2; h1 += h3; h1 += h4;
  h2 += h1; h3 += h1; h4 += h1;

  h1 = fmix32(h1);
  h2 = fmix32(h2);
  h3 = fmix32(h3);
  h4 = fmix32(h4);

  h1 += h2; h1 += h3; h1 += h4;
  h2 += h1; h3 += h1; h4 += h1;

  ((uint32_t*)out)[0] = h1;
  ((uint32_t*)out)[1] = h2;
  ((uint32_t*)out)[2] = h3;
  ((uint32_t*)out)[3] = h4;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void MurmurHash3_x64_128 ( const void * key, const int len,
                           const uint32_t seed, void * out )
{
  const uint8_t * data = (const uint8_t*)key;
  const int nblocks = len / 16;

  uint64_t h1 = seed;
  uint64_t h2 = seed;

  const uint64_t c1 = BIG_CONSTANT(0x87c37b91114253d5);
  const uint64_t c2 = BIG_CONSTANT(0x4cf5ad432745937f);

  //----------
  // body

  const uint64_t * blocks = (const uint64_t *)(data);

  for(int i = 0; i < nblocks; i++)
  {
    uint64_t k1 = getblock64(blocks,i*2+0);
    uint64_t k2 = getblock64(blocks,i*2+1);

    k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL64(k1,31); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;

    h1 = ROTL64(h1,27); h1 += h2; h1 = h1*5+0x52dce729;

    k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL64(k2,33); k2 *= c1; h2 ^= k2;

    h2 = ROTL64(h2,31); h2 += h1; h2 = h2*5+0x38495ab5;
  }

  //----------
  // tail

  const uint8_t * tail = (const uint8_t*)(data + nblocks*16);

  uint64_t k1 = 0;
  uint64_t k2 = 0;

  switch(len & 15)
  {
  case 15: k2 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[14]) << 48;
  case 14: k2 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[13]) << 40;
  case 13: k2 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[12]) << 32;
  case 12: k2 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[11]) << 24;
  case 11: k2 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[10]) << 16;
  case 10: k2 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 9]) << 8;
  case  9: k2 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 8]) << 0;
           k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL64(k2,33); k2 *= c1; h2 ^= k2;

  case  8: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 7]) << 56;
  case  7: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 6]) << 48;
  case  6: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 5]) << 40;
  case  5: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 4]) << 32;
  case  4: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 3]) << 24;
  case  3: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 2]) << 16;
  case  2: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 1]) << 8;
  case  1: k1 ^= ((uint64_t)tail[ 0]) << 0;
           k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL64(k1,31); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;
  };

  //----------
  // finalization

  h1 ^= len; h2 ^= len;

  h1 += h2;
  h2 += h1;

  h1 = fmix64(h1);
  h2 = fmix64(h2);

  h1 += h2;
  h2 += h1;

  ((uint64_t*)out)[0] = h1;
  ((uint64_t*)out)[1] = h2;
}
```

**MurmurHash3.h**

```
#ifndef _MURMURHASH3_H_
#define _MURMURHASH3_H_

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Platform-specific functions and macros

// Microsoft Visual Studio

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER < 1600)

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;

// Other compilers

#else   // defined(_MSC_VER)

#include <stdint.h>

#endif // !defined(_MSC_VER)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void MurmurHash3_x86_32  ( const void * key, int len, uint32_t seed, void * out );

void MurmurHash3_x86_128 ( const void * key, int len, uint32_t seed, void * out );

void MurmurHash3_x64_128 ( const void * key, int len, uint32_t seed, void * out );

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif // _MURMURHASH3_H_
```

**Testing.cpp**

```
#include "MurmurHash3.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  const char * hashToTest = "murmur3a";
  char  out[128] ;
  uint32_t seed = time(0);
  MurmurHash3_x64_128( hashToTest, strlen(hashToTest) , seed, out );
  for(int i=0 ; i<128 ;i++)
  cout<<(int) out[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;

}
```

I call the function MurmurHash3_x64_128 because I'm on a 64 bit system.
If you are on 32 bit you should call MurmurHash3_x86_128

But, for example, I get in *out*

```
-34  -106  32  -60  34  44  -30  -128  -127  -10  -75  25  73  -64  -50  31  -120  32  96  0  0  0  0  0  41  116  50  -56  7  127  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -32  -71  12  29  -3  127  0  0  -8  29  96  0  0  0  0  0  68  24  64  0  0  0  0  0  -8  -79  47  -56  7  127  0  0  -1  -1  0  0  1  0  0  0  -16  -71  12  29  -3  127  0  0  89  24  64  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -83  24  64  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  -3  127  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

There are also negative values. I'm not an expert of hash functions. Is it normal this behavior?
Furthermore I have the need of sort the hash values returned from more calls of the function. How can I compare hash values efficiently? With an XOR?

Another thing which makes me think I'm wrong is that the function return 2 different hash values for the same execution. Namely look at this code

**Testing.cpp**

```
#include "MurmurHash3.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  const char * hashToTest = "murmur3a";
  char  out[128] ;
  char  out2[128] ;
  uint32_t seed = time(0);
  MurmurHash3_x64_128( hashToTest, strlen(hashToTest) , seed, out );
  MurmurHash3_x64_128( hashToTest, strlen(hashToTest) , seed, out2 );
  for(int i=0 ; i<128 ;i++)
  cout<<(int) out[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;

  for(int i=0 ; i<128 ;i++)
  cout<<(int) out2[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;

}
```

I get 2 different hash values:

```
-93  -105  98  -119  -121  125  76  -5  -48  -108  51  -50  18  -74  -72  2  -24  -68  37  32  -4  127  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -80  -69  37  32  -4  127  0  0  -9  102  56  -80  99  127  0  0  1  0  0  0  99  127  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -80  -81  53  -80  99  127  0  0  -40  40  -53  -81  99  127  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -80  -69  37  32  -4  127  0  0  -8  29  96  0  0  0  0  0  -91  -42  56  -80  99  127  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  

-93  -105  98  -119  -121  125  76  -5  -48  -108  51  -50  18  -74  -72  2  -128  32  96  0  0  0  0  0  41  100  -50  -81  99  127  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -80  -69  37  32  -4  127  0  0  -8  29  96  0  0  0  0  0  79  24  64  0  0  0  0  0  -8  -95  -53  -81  99  127  0  0  -1  -1  0  0  1  0  0  0  -64  -69  37  32  -4  127  0  0  100  24  64  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -67  24  64  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  -4  127  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

(I'm using C++11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get 2 different hash values:

One problem is that you're printing out 128 bytes of data, but MurmurHash3() only outputs 128 *bits*.  That means that only the first (128/8)=16 bytes of each line of your output are valid hash data; the remaining bytes you are printing out are uninitialized/random data that isn't meaningful.

A second reason is mentioned on the [MurmurHash3() Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) page:

> When using 128-bits, the x86 and x64 versions do not produce the same
>   values, as the algorithms are optimized for their respective
>   platforms.

On to the next part...

> There are also negative values. I'm not an expert of hash functions.
>   Is it normal this behavior?

Whether the values are negative or not depends on how the data-printing mechanism interprets the bytes.  Currently you're printing the values out as if they were `int`s, and `int` is a signed data type, which means that any value that has the most-significant-bit set will be printed as a negative value.  If you want to see the values printed as unsigned, you should cast them to (unsigned int) before passing them to cout, instead.

> How can I compare hash values efficiently?

[memcmp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html) is one common way to compare the contents of two arbitrary memory buffers.

Comment: He only calls `time(0)` once before he calls `MurmurHash`, and uses the same `seed` value for both.

Comment: Yes, I see that -- I'll fix my answer.

Comment: You answered all of my questions. Thanks. I did 2 stupid mistakes. I forgot a thing. If I want etablish inside the code if I'm on a 32 or 64 bit system can I use:      if(sizeof(void *) ==8)   ??  Or is there a more clever method?